# setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint) hides Qt Window

Tags: c++, windows, qt, windows-7, qt5

I want to make my Qt Window stay on top. When `setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)` is executed, the window becomes hidden (on Windows 7).

I've also tried:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
setWindowFlags(flags | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

And, it still does the same. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Call show() after you set the flag:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
setWindowFlags(flags | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
show();
```

Check out http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop

Comment: Nothing wrong with this answer, just that: windowFlags / setWindowFlags is a child of the window you are using. So it might need to be ThisWindow.windowFlags() and ThisWindow.setWindowFlags(...) and ThisWindow.show() depending on your context.