# Force QApplication using QQmlApplicationEngine to be on foreground

Tags: windows, qt, qqmlapplicationengine, setforegroundwindow

I am trying to force my application to stay on top of everything even when other processes pop up. Here's a simplified version of my `main`:

**main.cpp**

```
QApplication                        app{argc, argv};
QQmlApplicationEngine               engine;

engine.load(QUrl{"qrc:/file.qml"});

return app.exec();
```

I need a solution for both `Windows` and `Linux`. However the priority is to the former and there doesn't seem to be a `Qt` solution. Here's what I tried:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    HWND hCurWnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();
    DWORD dwMyID = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
    DWORD dwCurID = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hCurWnd, NULL);
    ::AttachThreadInput(dwCurID, dwMyID, TRUE);
    ::SetWindowPos(hCurWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
    ::SetWindowPos(hCurWnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
    bool ok = ::SetForegroundWindow(hCurWnd);
    LOG_INFO() << ok;
    ::AttachThreadInput(dwCurID, dwMyID, FALSE);
    ::SetFocus(hCurWnd);
    ::SetActiveWindow(hCurWnd);
#endif
```

`ok` returns `true` but it doesn't seem to work. External processes still appear on top of the application after its start.

The loaded `QML` file has its `visibility` set on `FullScreen`. Its type is `ApplicationWindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind it was dumb simple:

[setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint) hides Qt Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097323/setwindowflagsqtwindowstaysontophint-hides-qt-window)

Therefore I wrote this in my **file.qml**:

```
ApplicationWindow
{
    visibility: "FullScreen"
    flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
}
```